# How to show an alert in case of HTTP error 404.3

Tags: javascript

I'm trying open a document in `window.open()` which throws

> HTTP error 404.3

Now I know the solution with `IIS Settings` or setting `staticContent` in web.config. But I just want to show an alert in case of 404.3 error.

Comment: You can surround `windows.open()` with `try{windows.open()}catch(){..}`

Comment: I tried to use `try` and `catch` but it will still open the `url` and then throw error. What I wanted to do is not open the `url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution which worked for me.

```
            var XMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            XMLHttp.open("GET", "" + url + "");
            XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = handlerFunction;
            XMLHttp.send(null);
            function handlerFunction() {
                if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4 && XMLHttp.status == 404) {
                    alert("File not reachable");
                }
                else if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4 && XMLHttp.status !== 404) {
                    window.open(url, '_blank');
                }
            }
```

Comment: You should use a "HEAD" request instead of a "GET" request if you want to just check that the page exists.

Answer (score 0):

If  you get a 404.3 error, your code is not going to be interpreted, so IIS Settings is the solution here

Comment: As per my understanding, 404.3 is a server side error. So the code will be interpreted and executed on the browser. And the error will happen only when we will access certain page which is not reachable.

Comment: In my case, i had to set my application pool to .net framework 4.0, by default was 2.0

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on your scenario how you want to interpret Error type in error page.

As you know Error 404.3 happened in server side (IIS) not in client side so it must be controlled in IIS web.config or something in back-end, but in easy way you can redirect user to a page with specific query string to error page and in error page control query string !!

For example take a look at this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="LogIn.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="ErrorPages/Oops.html?Error=NoAccess"/>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorPages/Oops.html?Error=FileNotFound"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="ErrorPages/Oops.html?Error=ServerError"/>
</customErrors>
```

in `Oops.html` read query string and show your alert:

```
  function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and in load:

```
  switch (getParameterByName("Error")) {
    case 'NoAccess':
        alert('The page you are looking for is not exist in the system.');
        break;
    case "FileNotFound":
        alert('File not found.');
        break;
    case "ServerError":
        alert('Error in server.');
        break;
    default:
        break
}
```